# Dice Roll Simulation in Java

Tags: java

i searched this site and found similar codes but a little different. For my lab in class the instructions say that I need to roll N die , M times and display the number of times a roll occurs in a frequency table. so I'm having a bit of trouble setting up the data in my frequency table. The frequency table prints right but my numbers are wrong. I feel like I'm missing something either and array or an increment? Please Help

my input:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab1
{


  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
       Random ran = new Random();
       String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many dice?: ");
       String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many rolls?: ");
       int die = Integer.parseInt(n);
       int roll = Integer.parseInt(m);
       int count = 0;
       int[] rollArr = new int[die*6+1];

       for(int i=0;i<rollArr.length;i++)
       {
            rollArr[i] = 0;
       }

       for( int i=0; i<roll;i++)
       {
            count = die*1 + ran.nextInt ( 6 );
            ++rollArr[count];
       }

       for(int r=1;r<rollArr.length;r++)
            System.out.println(r + ":" + rollArr[r]);
  }
}
```

The example says to roll 4 dice 1,000,000 times to get a bell curve but my curve has alot of zeroes.
my output:

```
1:0
2:0
3:0
4:166309
5:166424
6:166523
7:166984
8:167286
9:166474
10:0
11:0
12:0
13:0
14:0
15:0
16:0
17:0
18:0
19:0
20:0
21:0
22:0
23:0
24:0
```

Comment: `count = die*1 + ran.nextInt ( 6 );` this doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain it?

Comment: The `count` is me rolling the N dice randomly. then I add it to my array. I originally had it `++rollArr[die*1+ran.nextInt(6);`

Comment: So, that line.  If you use the values from the exercise, you get count = 4 + [a random number from 0 - 5]   You are using that as the index of the array to increment.  That is why you get the clustering around 4-9.  You probably want to in increment the value at the index of the actual roll.  Divide and conquer - solve this for one die first and then expand.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So to increment the value of the index of the actual roll I would use my number of rolls and randomize?

Comment: No need to initialize your array with 0's. That's the default value it is set to at declaration http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just give a hint since this is a lab assignment.

I believe your instructor wants to see the distribution of *sums* of the die rolls, since that's what will show up as a bell curve. So your array would have to capture and count the possible sums. For example, if you rolled four dice, then the possible sums are 4-24, and you would tally those up.

Comment: Also can be important to give your Random object a new seed every time you run the program - `Random ran = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());`. Otherwise it's not truly random.

Comment: So I'm adding the possibles sums for each roll ?

Comment: @Andrew : Not really related to my answer in particular, but new Random() takes care of this automatically.

Comment: Yeah that was supposed to be on the question, not the answer, whoops. I seem to remember new Random() was sometimes deterministic, depending on what VM you are using.

Comment: @Bryanna : Each roll of n dice yields a sum. So if you roll 4 dice then you can get a sum in the range 4-24. Whatever that sum is, go to your roll array and increment the corresponding array element.

Comment: Okay so I'm incrementing the array at each sum? That's within the for loop right?

Comment: There should be exactly two for loops, one inside the other. The first loop ranges over the rolls (like if you're doing 1,000,000 rolls), and the second loop--inside the first--ranges over the n dice. The incrementing happens after the second loop, because now you have a sum of the n dice for that roll. I'll leave it at that so you can explore the rest yourself.

Comment: Ahh okay! I did that before but I thought I was wrong. So I need to increment within the second for loop the index of the actual roll.